# Rewrite URL Rule to strip URL segment

Tags: .net, azure, url-rewriting, url-routing, azure-web-app-service

Ho can I set up a rewrite rule in web.config:

From:

https://cats.animals.co.uk/kittens/Docs.aspx?p1=115&p2=8&p3=200309.......

To:

https://cats.animals.co.uk/Docs.aspx?p1=115&p2=8&p3=200309.......

Without the "kittens" part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just like you would with IIS. You will need to do it by adding it to your web.config. This is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to the Microsoft documentation.

The pattern that you want, note this should be close.

^/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)

The rewrite since you really only want the second part:

{R:2}

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
    </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem do work URL stays the same

Comment: Have you restarted?